# How can I update object keys/values when if statement is triggered?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, discord.js

I'm building a Discord bot which will allow users to create custom commands.

It works in this way, user enters "!addcommand !commandname:command value". The program will then split the string, and add !commandname:command value to a txt file. Whenever somebody types !commandname into discord, the bot will then output "command value" into chat.

The program is supposed to check if the new command exists whenever an if statement is triggered. However, this only seems to be checking the first time the program is run, which causes new commands to not be recognized unless the program is restarted.

Note:

1. Client.on listens to the channel, and contents are run every time someone says something in chat.
2. !addcommand appears to be functioning correctly, and I'm able to confirm the lines are being written to the file as intended.

I don't know what else to try.

Main file:

```
//Assume that requires etc are included


client.on('message', message => {

  const pingCheck = message.content.charAt(0);
  const commandCheck = message.content.split(" ");

  if (pingCheck === "!") {
    //Populates the list of custom commands. Must be done on every check, or new commands will not be recognized.
    //Currently, this seems to only update once the service/program is restarted
    var commandList = customCommands.returnPhrase();

    //If the commandList object contains the correct key (stored in commandCheck[0]) such as !commandname, the bot will send the value "command value" as a string to the discord chat.
    if (commandList.hasOwnProperty(commandCheck[0])) {
      message.channel.send(commandList[commandCheck[0]]);
    } 

    //If the key does not exist, the program then checks predefined commands. Other commands exist here, but for the purposes of this question I'll show only the !addcommand, which is used to create a new custom command.
    else {
            switch (commandCheck[0]) {
        case "!addcommand":

        //This checks that the command is formatted properly, "!commandname:commandvalue". If it does not start with ! or contain : somewhere in the string, it's probably an invalid format.
        //Technically this still allows for a !:commandvalue format. I haven't implemented a check for this yet.
                if (commandCheck[1].startsWith("!") && commandCheck[1].includes(":")) {

                  //While loop reconstructs the command key to be passed in, ignores slot 0 as this is the !addcommand
                  var gs = "";
                  var x = 1;

                  while (x < commandCheck.length) {
                      gs += gs +commandCheck[x] + " ";
                      x++;
                  }

                  gs = gs.slice(0,-1)+"\r\n"; //removes the last " " from the input string, and adds line-break

                  addCommands.addPhrase(gs);//passes reconstructed command to be added to commandlist.txt
                  message.channel.send("I have added " + commandCheck[1] + " to the command list.");

          break;
          }

        default:
          message.channel.send("I dont recognize that command.");

      }
    }
  }      
});
```

Module which adds commands:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var createCommand = {

    addPhrase: function(x) {
        fs.appendFile("commandlist.txt", x, function(err){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(err)
        });
    }

}

module.exports = createCommand;
```

Module which populates list of custom commands:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var commandFile = fs.readFileSync('commandlist.txt','utf8');
var dataSplit = commandFile.split("\r\n");

var readCommand = {
    returnPhrase: function(){
        var splitSplit = {};
        var i = 0;

        //populates splitSplit with keys and values based on text file
        while (i<dataSplit.length){
            var newKey = dataSplit[i].split(':');
            splitSplit[newKey[0]] = newKey[1];
            i++
        };

        return splitSplit;
    },
};

module.exports = readCommand;
```

Better readability: https://repl.it/repls/DarkvioletDeafeningAutomaticparallelization

Expected: commandList is populated everytime if statement is triggered

Actual: commandList populates first time statement is triggered

Comment: What happens if you restart the server? Do the commands get added?

Comment: @JonasWilms yes, the commands exist on restart. The commands are being written to the file correctly, it seems like they just aren't updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write to the file whenever a new command comes in, however you only read once from it when the server starts, so you won't keep track of changes (untill you restart the server which will read the file again). Now you could theoretically listen for filechanges and reload then, but that is overcomplicating things, the filesystem is not meant to achieve that. Instead, just keep your commands in an object and export some methods for adding / checking:

```
let commands = {};

// ¹

module.exports = {
 addCommand(key, value) {
   commands[key] = value;
   // ²
 },
 getValue(key) {
   return commands[key];
 }
};
```

Now when you add a command, it directly gets added to the object, and that can then directly be read out.

---

Now as objects aren't persisted accross restarts, you will lose all commands then. But that is easy to fix: You could just reflect the object to a file whenever it updates, and then load it on every start. Instead of creating a custom format for that, I'd just use JSON. The code above can easily be extended:

```
// ¹
try {
 commands = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync("commands.txt") );
} catch(e) { /* ignore if file doesnt exist yet */ }

// ²
fs.writeFile("commands.txt", JSON.stringify(commands), err => {
  if(err) console.error(err);
});
```

---

How I would write the bot:

```
const playerCommands = require("./commands.js");

const defaultCommands = {
   addCommand(...pairs) {
    let result = "";
    for(const pair of pairs) {
       const [name, value] = pair.split(":");
       playerCommands.addCommand(name, value);
       result += `${name} added with value ${value}\n`;
    }
   return result;     
   }
};

client.on('message', ({ content, channel }) => {     
  if(content[0] !== "!") return; // ignore non-commandd

  const [commandName, ...args] = content.slice(1).split(" ");

  if(defaultCommands[commandName]) 
    return channel.send(defaultCommands[commandName](...args));

  const value = playerCommands.getValue(commandName);
  if(value) return channel.send(value);

  return channel.send("Command not found!");
});
```

Comment: The list _should_ be repopulating whenever the if statement finds that the message starts with "!"

```

if (pingCheck === "!") {
    var commandList = customCommands.returnPhrase();
```

This is checked every time a message is sent in the discord channel.
Technically your solution would work, but I need the commands to be available after restarting the service.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with JSON, however saving the objects to the file, and loading on startup seems like a better solution. Your code also gave me some ideas on ways to make mine more concise. Thanks for the help!